# JavaScript - text with numbers to uppercase

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase

I have seemingly random strings in javascript

```
var str = "abc123aaa2";
```

but I need to transform the letters to uppercase

```
var str = "ABC123AAA2";
```

I can't use any library, just vanilla JS.
I tried using

```
str.toUpperCase();
```

but that returns undefined?

Can anyone help me with a speedy workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you are trying:

```
var str = 'abc123aaa2';
/* ...*/
str.toUpperCase();
/* some action on str */
```

That's not how it works. Strings are *[immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)*. You need to reassign `str`, if you want its value be the uppercased value:

```
var str = "abc123aaa2";
// later
str = str.toUpperCase();
// or at once:
var str = "abc123aaa2".toUpperCase();
```

Comment: How is this different than what the OP's got?

Comment: @JosephSilber OP did not assign the result of `toUpperCase` anywhere. `toUpperCase` does not modify the original string; it returns a new string that has been uppercased.

Comment: OP said: "but that **returns undefined**".

Comment: @JosephSilber: try `console.log(str)` after the assignment

Comment: @KooiInc - I know that this works!!! All I'm saying is that the OP seemingly has some other problem, as this is what they've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

toUppercase method of strings in JavaScript does not mutate the original variable. So what you need to do is to reassign what toUpperCase method is returning to the str variable

```
var str = "abc123aaa2";
str = str.toUpperCase()
```